# Is there any way to set element position relative to static parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with static position and can't change it (because all will break then). And I need to add a child element, with relative position to it. Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Adding `position:relative` to a child of a statically positioned element will do *vitually nothing* by itself. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes. But it's important to remember that the child will always be relative to the parent. It would be easier to help if you tell us what your expected outcome is. What is it that you want to happen on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a relative child, simply make a relative container and add your child element within that.

```
<div class="static">
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.static {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    position: static;
    width: 200px;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I've created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7L6bgruh/

Answer (score 1):

An element with `position: static` is *non*-positioned. You cannot position an element relative to another element that's itself not positioned, even if that element serves as its containing block in normal circumstances.